# Calling a directive method on load of the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div hello ng-click="hello()">directive</div>
</div>
```

I am calling a function `onclick`, is there a way i can call the method on the load of the `template` to load the data. I tried `ng-init`, but its not working.

```
    angular.module('myApp', [ ])
.directive('hello',function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.on('click',function(){
                alert('clicked');
            });
            element.on("load", function(){
                alert("loaded");
            });
        }
      };
    }
  );
```

Comment: do you wanted to call directive method from controller?

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1574/

Comment: @freak_head on which template load you want to call this function..I don't see any function in your directive

Answer (score 1):

Call the function in the 'compile' block of the directive instead of 'link' block. If you want to execute a function while loading of the directive(compiling phase). I hope that will do the trick.